# Notice: Undefined index when use utf-8 character in php

Tags: php, csv, utf-8

I want to display `CSV` file information as an array in a foreach and show on table
But i have this error when i use UTF-8 character
Someone can help. Thank you

> Notice: Undefined index: Crop

This is my var_dump

```
 array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'Crop' => string 'سیب' (length=16)
      'Area' => string '5772' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'Crop' => string 'پرتقال' (length=10)
      'Area' => string '709' (length=3)
```

This is my code

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
echo '<tr>
        <td>' . $value['Area'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $value["Crop"] . '</td>
      </tr>';
}
```

Comment: Your code is working as intended. Are you sure that you are assigning this array to `$data` variable or you don't override this variable after assignment? Error suggests your issue has nothing to do with UTF-8 but with plain simple `Crop` item not existing in array.

Comment: https://eval.in/937065 your code working fine

Comment: yes im sure $data variable is not override.I think of utf-8 because Area is displayed correctly @StormoPL

Comment: @mary: Try to debug it step by step. Start with `var_dump($value)` inside the `foreach` loop - check if `Crop` exists there. Than check if you haven't put space inside quotation marks. And finally, try to switch double quotations to single (it's completly wild guess and should not matter but `Area` works). There is either something wrong with your array (which is outside of provided code) or with index name cause you have 2 separate confirmation that what you have posted works.